# dynamic programming approach for max sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

[GOLD MINE PROBLEM](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gold-mine-problem/)

This was asked in  an interview question but I am not able to understand the test cases

Like in ex 1->I know that max ans is coming on adding 6,4,2 but how {(1,0)->(2,1)->(2,2)} these move taking these values 6,4,2;
and
on (1,0) it will move top to bottom which is not a valid move

**Gold Mine Problem**

Given a gold mine of n*m dimensions. Each field in this mine contains a positive integer which is the amount of gold in tons. Initially the miner is at first column but can be at any row. He can move only (right->,right up /,right down) that is from a given cell, the miner can move to the cell diagonally up towards the right or right or diagonally down towards the right. Find out maximum amount of gold he can collect.

```
    Input : mat[][] = {{1, 3, 3},
                       {2, 1, 4},
                      {0, 6, 4}};
    Output : 12 
    {(1,0)->(2,1)->(2,2)}

    Input: mat[][] = { {1, 3, 1, 5},
                       {2, 2, 4, 1},
                       {5, 0, 2, 3},
                       {0, 6, 1, 2}};
    Output : 16
    (2,0) -> (1,1) -> (1,2) -> (0,3) OR
    (2,0) -> (3,1) -> (2,2) -> (2,3)

    Input : mat[][] = {{10, 33, 13, 15},
                      {22, 21, 04, 1},
                      {5, 0, 2, 3},
                      {0, 6, 14, 2}};
    Output : 83
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you misunderstood the notation.

```
   C0 - C1 - C2 
R0 1    3    3
R1 2    1    4
R2 0    6    4
```

Rows are marked with R and Columns with C.

> ```
> Output : 12 
> {(1,0)->(2,1)->(2,2)}
> ```

Means:

{(R1, C0) -> (R2, C1) -> (R2, C2)}

- Since you can start on any row of the first column, you start on column 1.
- Then move **right-down**
- Then move **right**.

The same notation is used on the other example. Hope this helped!